# Are X, Y correlated and independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance

I have a problem from my textbook:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be independent events. Show that $X = I_A + I_B$ and $Y=|I_A − I_B|$ are uncorrelated. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I've managed to shown that they're uncorrelated by solving for $Cov(X,Y)$. This was shown to be $0$, thus uncorrelated. However, I'm struggling to show whether they're independent or not.

If we also let $p(A) := p$, we can try to find $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Thereafter, we can try to solve for $f_X$ and $f_Y$ separately, and check for independence. However, I don't really know how to form $f_{X,Y}$, so I started the other way around.

$$ f_X(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
2p(1-p), \quad x = 0,2 \\ p^2+(1-p)^2,\quad  x = 1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$ f_Y(y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
2p(1-p), \quad y = 1 \\ p^2+(1-p)^2, \quad y = 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

But how do we find $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ here really?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Consider examples.  Say that your two initial events were supported on $\{0,1\}$.  Then show that the parity of $X$ equals the parity of $Y$.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry, but I haven't used parity before. So I don't really know how to apply that in this problem

Comment: Well, you don't need to use parity here...you can just work out the joint distribution. That's easy enough.  The parity remark is even easier to use and spares you the arithmetic, but there is no need to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation of $f_X$ is wrong. You seem to assume that $P(B)=P(A)$ , I don't know why.

Let instead $p=P(A)$, $q=p(B)$

Then $$\begin{align}
P(X=0) &=(1-p)(1-q)  \\
P(X=1) &=(1-p)q + (1-q)p  \\
P(X=2) &=p\,q  \\
\end{align}
$$
and

$$\begin{align}
P(Y=0) &=p  q + (1-p)(1-q)  \\
P(Y=1) &= (1-p)q + (1-q)p  \\
\end{align}
$$

You can also compute the joint probability, and check that $P(X Y) \ne P(X)P(Y)$. But that's really not needed.

Just noticing that $X= 1 \iff Y=1$ tells you that the $X,Y$ are not independent.

Namely, $P(X=1 , Y=0)=0$. But $P(X=1) P(Y=0) > 0$. Hence you've found a pair such that $P(X Y) \ne P(X)P(Y)$, they are not independent.